# Join two jsons based on element

Tags: java, json, mule-studio

I have two json files. I need to parse and join the json into a single structure

lineage.json

```
{
   "lineage": [{
        "sourceColumnId": "VMB_BESTADDRESS.SNAPSHOT_TS",
        "description": "",
        "targetColumnId": "VMB_BESTADDRESSUSAGE.NXREINS"
    },
    {
        "sourceColumnId": "DSL_RECORD_SOURCES.MAMACT",
        "description": "",
        "targetColumnId": "G2_ZUMADF00.MAMACT"
    },
    {
        "sourceColumnId": "DSL_RECORD_SOURCES.MAMADE",
        "description": "",
        "targetColumnId": "G2_ZUMADF00.HDF_S_POL_GEN"
    }]
}
```

column.json

```
{
    "column": [{
        "ID": 39700,
        "columnId": "VMB_BESTADDRESS.SNAPSHOT_TS",
        "column": "SNAPSHOT_TS",
        "dataType": "String",
        "length": "",
        "table": "VMB_BESTADDRESS",
    },
    {
        "ID": 39701,
        "columnId": "VMB_BESTADDRESSUSAGE.NXREINS",
        "column": "NXREINS",
        "dataType": "String",
        "length": "",
        "table": "VMB_BESTADDRESSUSAGE",

    },
    {
        "ID": 39702,
        "columnId": "VMB_BESTADDRESSUSAGE.PKADDRESSCODE",
        "column": "PKADDRESSCODE",
        "dataType": "String",
        "length": "",
        "table": "VMB_BESTADDRESSUSAGE",
    }]
}
```

I need to join the two jsons such that for every match of sourcecolumnId and targetcolumnid in column the following json structure must be populated

```
{
    output:{
        sourceColumnId:VMB_BESTADDRESS.SNAPSHOT_TS,
        sourceColumnName:SNAPSHOT_TS,
        targetColumnId:VMB_BESTADDRESSUSAGE.NXREINS,
        targetColumnNameNXREINS,
    }
}
```

I need to join lookup two json to get the output such that

sourceColumnName -> column name from column.json whose columnId and sourceColumnId are same.
similarly for targetcolumnName also.

Comment: Yes.  So what is your question?

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx I need to join lookup two json to get the output

Answer (score 0):

```
    String str = "xxx";     // column.json

    JSONArray jsonArrayColumn = JSON.parseObject(str);
    Map<String, JSONObject> column = new HashMap();     // {id:name}
    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArrayColumn.size(); i++){    // loop
        JSONObject obj = jsonArrayColumn.getJSONObject(i);
        column.put(obj.getString("columnId"), obj.getString("column"));
    }

    String str2 = "xxx";    // lineage.json
    JSONArray jsonArrayLineage = JSON.parseObject(str2);

    JSONArray resultArray = new JSONArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArrayLineage.size(); i++){   // loop
        JSONObject lineageObj = jsonArrayLineage.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("sourceColumnId", lineageObj.get("sourceColumnId"));
        obj.put("sourceColumnName", column.get(lineageObj.get("sourceColumnId")));
        obj.put("targetColumnId", lineageObj.get("targetColumnId"));
        obj.put("targetColumnName", column.get(lineageObj.get("targetColumnId")));
    }
```

The `resultArray` is what you want.